# Texture in 3D view won't update as I manipulate the UVs in the UV Editor

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm a new Blender user coming from 3DSMax and Maya, and the UV editor behavior is really weird. Any changes I make to the UVs in the UV editor won't show up on the 3D view.

As you can see, even if I overly stretch the UVs the texture continues the same on the object.

I think it's a setting issue since it can be done in Blender, as seen on this video https://youtu.be/SnKNTANTtd8?t=437

What can I do to solve this? Using Blender 2.8 currently.

[image][[image: [2]]

Comment: Where have you specified which coordinates your texture should be using?

Comment: I didn't, so there was the problem, as Emir showed bellow. The thing is that it seems if I just select a default Blender texture, such as Checker or Brick texture, I need to add those additional nodes for it to work. If I just select Image Texture and import an image, I don't need those nodes and it works as it should. I'm still used with the way Max or Maya works, so it's just an unfamiliarity issue with Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Mapping Node and a texture coordinate node.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Still it seems a bit troublesome to add those nodes everytime I want to add a texture, is there a way to add them automatically? For clarification, the way I added it was clicking on that little circle in Base Color on the material properties tab and selecting Checker Texture.

Comment: Just for clarification, I found that if I select Image Texture instead of Checker or Brick textures, it works without the need of additional nodes, at least for UVing, so now it's working as I expected.